# Javafx stage.setFullScreen throw exception after gluon:build and .exe run but not after javafx:run

Tags: java, javafx, gluonfx, gluon-desktop

I'm trying to create my first .exe from a javafx application. I'm using maven and gluon to achieve my goal.
When I launch my app with mvn javafx:run everything run fine.
So I try to package my app in a .exe using gluonfx:build and I get a .exe, everything seems okay, I have no error in maven build or link log.
Unfortunately when I try to run the .exe nothing happened, I have this log using gluonfx:nativerun :

```
[jeu. nov. 17 21:01:45 CET 2022][INFO] ==================== RUN TASK ====================
[jeu. nov. 17 21:01:45 CET 2022][INFO] [SUB] nov. 17, 2022 9:01:45 PM com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl startup
[jeu. nov. 17 21:01:45 CET 2022][INFO] [SUB] WARNING: Unsupported JavaFX configuration: classes were loaded from 'unnamed module @6b71769e'
[jeu. nov. 17 21:01:46 CET 2022][INFO] [SUB] Exception in Application start method
[jeu. nov. 17 21:01:46 CET 2022][INFO] [SUB] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
[jeu. nov. 17 21:01:46 CET 2022][INFO] [SUB]    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:901)
[jeu. nov. 17 21:01:46 CET 2022][INFO] [SUB]    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:196)
[jeu. nov. 17 21:01:46 CET 2022][INFO] [SUB]    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
[jeu. nov. 17 21:01:46 CET 2022][INFO] [SUB]    at com.oracle.svm.core.thread.PlatformThreads.threadStartRoutine(PlatformThreads.java:704)
[jeu. nov. 17 21:01:46 CET 2022][INFO] [SUB]    at com.oracle.svm.core.windows.WindowsPlatformThreads.osThreadStartRoutine(WindowsPlatformThreads.java:143)
[jeu. nov. 17 21:01:46 CET 2022][INFO] [SUB] Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.OverlayWarning
[jeu. nov. 17 21:01:46 CET 2022][INFO] [SUB]    at com.sun.javafx.util.Utils.forceInit(Utils.java:869)
[jeu. nov. 17 21:01:46 CET 2022][INFO] [SUB]    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.OverlayWarningHelper.<clinit>(OverlayWarningHelper.java:44)
[jeu. nov. 17 21:01:46 CET 2022][INFO] [SUB]    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.OverlayWarning.<clinit>(OverlayWarning.java:50)
[jeu. nov. 17 21:01:46 CET 2022][INFO] [SUB]    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.WindowStage.applyFullScreen(WindowStage.java:685)
[jeu. nov. 17 21:01:46 CET 2022][INFO] [SUB]    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.WindowStage.setFullScreen(WindowStage.java:734)
[jeu. nov. 17 21:01:46 CET 2022][INFO] [SUB]    at javafx.stage.Stage.doVisibleChanged(Stage.java:1184)
[jeu. nov. 17 21:01:46 CET 2022][INFO] [SUB]    at javafx.stage.Stage$1.doVisibleChanged(Stage.java:190)
[jeu. nov. 17 21:01:46 CET 2022][INFO] [SUB]    at com.sun.javafx.stage.StageHelper.visibleChangedImpl(StageHelper.java:63)
[jeu. nov. 17 21:01:46 CET 2022][INFO] [SUB]    at com.sun.javafx.stage.WindowHelper.visibleChanged(WindowHelper.java:77)
[jeu. nov. 17 21:01:46 CET 2022][INFO] [SUB]    at javafx.stage.Window$12.invalidated(Window.java:1212)
[jeu. nov. 17 21:01:46 CET 2022][INFO] [SUB]    at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(BooleanPropertyBase.java:110)
[jeu. nov. 17 21:01:46 CET 2022][INFO] [SUB]    at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.set(BooleanPropertyBase.java:145)
[jeu. nov. 17 21:01:46 CET 2022][INFO] [SUB]    at javafx.stage.Window.setShowing(Window.java:1239)
[jeu. nov. 17 21:01:46 CET 2022][INFO] [SUB]    at javafx.stage.Window.show(Window.java:1254)
[jeu. nov. 17 21:01:46 CET 2022][INFO] [SUB]    at javafx.stage.Stage.show(Stage.java:277)
[jeu. nov. 17 21:01:46 CET 2022][INFO] [SUB]    at fr.icom.info.m1.balleauprisonnier_fx.App.start(App.java:115)
[jeu. nov. 17 21:01:46 CET 2022][INFO] [SUB]    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:847)
[jeu. nov. 17 21:01:46 CET 2022][INFO] [SUB]    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:484)
[jeu. nov. 17 21:01:46 CET 2022][INFO] [SUB]    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:457)
[jeu. nov. 17 21:01:46 CET 2022][INFO] [SUB]    at java.security.AccessController.executePrivileged(AccessController.java:169)
[jeu. nov. 17 21:01:46 CET 2022][INFO] [SUB]    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
[jeu. nov. 17 21:01:46 CET 2022][INFO] [SUB]    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:456)
[jeu. nov. 17 21:01:46 CET 2022][INFO] [SUB]    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
[jeu. nov. 17 21:01:46 CET 2022][INFO] [SUB]    at com.oracle.svm.jni.JNIJavaCallWrappers.jniInvoke_VA_LIST_Runnable_run_16403f8d32adb631126daa893e5e80085c5d6325(JNIJavaCallWrappers.java:0)
[jeu. nov. 17 21:01:46 CET 2022][INFO] [SUB]    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(WinApplication.java)
[jeu. nov. 17 21:01:46 CET 2022][INFO] [SUB]    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:184)
[jeu. nov. 17 21:01:46 CET 2022][INFO] [SUB]    ... 3 more
[jeu. nov. 17 21:01:46 CET 2022][INFO] [SUB] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.OverlayWarning
[jeu. nov. 17 21:01:46 CET 2022][INFO] [SUB]    at java.lang.Class.forName(DynamicHub.java:1121)
[jeu. nov. 17 21:01:46 CET 2022][INFO] [SUB]    at com.sun.javafx.util.Utils.forceInit(Utils.java:866)
[jeu. nov. 17 21:01:46 CET 2022][INFO] [SUB]    ... 28 more
```

It appears to be the line `stage.setFullScreen(true);` in my App.java file that makes my .exe not running because when I replace it with `stage.setMaximized(true);` my .exe is launching correctly.

As the gluon documentation says (https://docs.gluonhq.com/#platforms_windows) I have installed graalvm-svm-java17-windows-gluon-22.1.0.1-Final, and the required visual studio things, like windows sdk, latest msvc version ...
My java and javafx version are 17.0.1

I first thought about a javafx version problem so I change it to 11 but the same problem happens, as the problem doesn't show using javafx:run I really don't know where the problem may come from ...

Here is my pom.xml file, maybe it will helps.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>fr.icom.info.m1.</groupId>
  <artifactId>balleauprisonnier_fx</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>balleauprisonnier_fx</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.target>9</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>9</maven.compiler.source>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <javafx.version>17.0.1</javafx.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
      <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
      <version>${javafx.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
      <artifactId>javafx-web</artifactId>
      <version>${javafx.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
      <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
      <version>${javafx.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
      <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
      <testSourceDirectory>test</testSourceDirectory>
      <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>ressources</directory>
        </resource>
     </resources>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
          <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>0.0.8</version>
          <configuration>
            <mainClass>fr.icom.info.m1.balleauprisonnier_fx.App</mainClass>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      

    <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>

                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <archive>
            <manifest>
                <mainClass>fr.icom.info.m1.balleauprisonnier_fx.App</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
                </configuration>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>

            </plugin>
            

<plugin>
    <groupId>com.gluonhq</groupId>
    <artifactId>gluonfx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.16</version>
    <configuration>
        <mainClass>fr.icom.info.m1.balleauprisonnier_fx.App</mainClass>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>copy-resources</id>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/gluonfx/x86_64-windows</outputDirectory>
              <resources>          
                <resource>
                  <directory>ressources</directory>
                  <filtering>true</filtering>
                </resource>
              </resources>              
            </configuration>            
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

            <!-- 
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.coderplus.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>copy-rename-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-file</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceFile>ressources/launcher_windows.bat</sourceFile>
                             <destinationFile>target/launcher_windows.bat</destinationFile>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>-->
            
      </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: When you go into full screen, by default JavaFX will display an overlay telling you the app went full screen and how to exit full screen. The error you're getting is saying the `com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.OverlayWarning` class is missing. You need to make sure that class is included in the native image, though I'm not sure how you do that.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to what @Slaw says I tried this code and it works:

```java
stage.setFullScreenExitKeyCombination(KeyCombination.NO_MATCH);
stage.setFullScreen(true);
```

Based on it's answer, I suppose that this code blocked the overlay warning and therefore no exception is thrown. Not sure of this one but my .exe works now, thank you !

Edit :
Based on what @José Pereda says I added `<reflectionList>com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.OverlayWarning</reflectionList>` to my pom.xml and it works fine, as it keeps the default behavior this answer seems to be a better one

Comment: That's a valid option, indeed, if you don't want your user to exit full mode. But if you still want the default behaviour, you can simply add the missing class `com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.OverlayWarning` to the `<reflectionList/>` in the configuration of the GluonFX plugin. Also you can run `mvn gluonfx:runagent` to find out all possible uses of reflection before you build the native image again. More here: https://docs.gluonhq.com/#_gluonfx_plugin_for_maven